# Multiprocessing only running the function and not the entire file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

If I run the following code, it would run the print("a") for every time that the pool.map runs.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import getpid

print("a")

def double(i):
    print("I'm process", getpid())
    return i * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(double, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        print(result)
```

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but in the code that I want to implement multiprocessing in has a long start up time which makes multiprocessing take a long time to get the result, which cancels out the time save of using multiprocessing. So is there a way to make it run only the function in parallel and not the entire file?

Comment: Why don't you relocate `print("a")` to the `if __name__ == '__main__'`-block you're already using?

Comment: Not the main issue, and not a practical solution to the code that I'm implementing this in

Comment: Well this _is_ the issue. Everything which isn't inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` gets re-executed. There's nothing special about `if __name__ == '__main__':`, it's just an if-statement. You can use it more than once to protect any code block from re-executing in a child process.

Comment: Bisous: It's all because of how `multiprocessing` works — i.e. the main script gets imported by each subprocess. So, as @Darkonaut suggested, your only recourse is going to be to put the `if` guard around any sections of code that should only execute when the script in run as the main process.

Comment: Obviously the code you show is just a conceptual example, but depending on your problem, if it is a numerical calculation for example, you might want to use numpy or numba. Or use a language for your calculation which does offer *true* multithreaded parallelism.

Comment: @darkonaut the problem is the time it takes to reload the module. even if it isn't executed because it is in the if-block, the interpreter still has to read through it

Comment: I'll try @Darkonaut 's solution, but it may be a bit complicated as for every new part of code that I need to put in, I will need to keep this in mind and I would also need to figure out the current portions of code that I will need to put in the if statement.

Comment: @AndrewPye The interpreter doesn't read past the if-statement, that's the whole point.

Comment: Make library modules for your definitions and let your `main.py` just import everything. Imports the child doesn't need go inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to run the function inside one process:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from os import getpid

print("a")

def double(i):
    print("I'm process", getpid())
    return i * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(double, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        print(result)
```

Prints (note the "garbled" output):

```
a
I'm processI'm process  I'm process 1
I'm process 1
I'm process1
 1
1
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Right, it allows one to "run the function inside _one process_", as any other thread-based mechanism. But the OP is asking about running functions _in parallel_, in multiple processes, not asynchronously.

Comment: @ForceBru If the function returns very quickly, such as `return i*2` here, then multiprocessing (as run every function in different process) won't help here. The start-up time of the process will be too high.

Comment: Of course, but threading will quickly become extremely slow once OP starts using it to attack their actual presumably CPU-intensive task. However, we don't know what that task is, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

this is one of the [major drawbacks of multiprocessing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-multiprocessing-and-multithreading/). The problem with starting an entire new python *process* is that it requires that overhead to re-import every module. If you are simply looking for a way to parallelize tasks, look into using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html).

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(double, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    print([f for f in futures])
```

You could also try to use multiprocessing on a larger portion of calculations!

Comment: [`ThreadPoolExecutor` uses threads, not processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) and thus suffers from the GIL. Looks like it's more about executing tasks _asynchronously_, not in parallel.

Comment: I understand that it uses threads. I was providing the resources so the question-asker could look into the different options, since it really does depend on the task they have.

Comment: Here's an article with a more in depth comparison... Main takeaway is that multiprocessing should only be used for CPU bound tasks. https://medium.com/@nyomanpradipta120/why-you-should-use-threadpoolexecutor-instead-processpoolexecutor-based-on-ctf-challenge-f51e838df351

Comment: The whole asyncio machinery and libraries where implemented to aid with I/O-limited tasks specifically, so yes, multiprocessing solves CPU-limited tasks, async threading solves I/O-limited tasks.